# moto metadata path has not been implemented

Tags: python, python-3.x, moto

Locally I can run Moto just fine.
When I run moto unit tests from Jenkins, I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: The /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/pkcs7 metadata path has not been implemented
```

I am trying to run tests which mock creating an s3 bucket.

Comment: The `latest/dynamic/..` is related to EC2 metadata - is  Jenkins trying to run other tests than `tests which mock creating an s3 bucket.`?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/verify-pkcs7.html

Comment: @BertBlommers yes, there are other unittests, but none for other aws services. Jenkins is running all unit tests under test/.

Comment: I don't think I should need to run any commands to validate pkcs. All of the tests using s3 are being mocked by moto. Locally I did not have to run anything like the linked you shared.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?